# Странное сообщение о необходимости правки

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено

Один из [позавчерашних вопросов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429090/) модератор совершенно справедливо пометил как требующий правки. Но автоматическое сообщение, которое появилось под вопросом, выглядит странно для тематики сайта по русскому языку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пример кода нам точно не нужен :)

Comment: Это более общая проблема описания причин закрытия вопросов. Было бы здорово переработать их все. Интересно то, что основные причины закрытия (первый экран) должны быть едины для Русского языка и Stack Overflow на русском, так как задаются переводом на Transifex. Причины «не по теме» уникальны для каждого сайта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Текст изменен:

> Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа
>   поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что
>   вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно
>   демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю средний абзац заменить таким описанием:

`Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, что именно вызвало у вас затруднения, и сообщите ваши мысли по данному вопросу.`

На мой взгляд оно тоже не идеально, будет здорово, если появятся ещё сформулированные версии.

Answer (score 1):

Этот вопрос надо было просто закрыть как домашнее задание. 
Ну право же, если человек просто копипастит сюда вопрос из задачника, это не слишком благодарная идея.

Что же до самой формулировки стандартного комментария, но ничто не мешает отвечающему написать вариант конкретно под ситуацию. Я обычно так и делаю, если вижу, что человек пришел сюда разобраться, а не списать готовое решение. А если видно, что он сам думать не хочет, то ему никакая формулировка не поможет.

Не возражаю, если она будет заменена на вашу. Или ваша будет добавлена как альтернативная.

Но мне кажется куда важнее формулировки выработать общий принцип отношения к таким вопросам. Да, есть голосовака - и это правильно. Но люди часто просто не понимают, чем надо руководствоваться, оценивая конкретный вопрос как домашнее задание. А некоторые просто рвутся отвечать, чем оказывают медвежью услугу не только очередному двоечнику, но, на мой взгляд, и всему ресурсу.

Ну и еще и примеры есть подобного. Человек задает десяток однотипных вопросов странного соджержания ("объясните мне этот текст"). Не слово, а именно текст. Ну сколько ж можно-то? Даже если ты иностранец, в чем я уже сомневаюсь. Вот что бы вы ему ответили, когда терпение лопается?

Comment: Я думаю, что человек, про которого идёт речь в конце, пытается заполнить анкету для работы в силовых отраслях. По его вопросам складывается такое впечатление. И русский язык у него может быть не родным, хотя он из России.

Я тоже считаю, что нужно в автоматическом тексте прямо указать, что сообщество ждёт от автора подробностей, какие усилия он приложил и что конкретно не получилось.